# Why doesn't this SVG display?

Tags: html, svg

I'm working on a project that uses svg. I generate this svg code thanks to an ocaml library:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:l="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="161.8mm" height="100mm" viewBox="0 0 161.8 100" color-profile="auto" color-interpolation="linearRGB" color-interpolation-filters="linearRGB">
  <g fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="9.98123" transform="matrix(100 0 0 -100 -0 100)">
    <defs>
      <path id="i1" d="M0 0L1.618 0L1.618 1L0 1Z"/>
    </defs>
    <use l:href="#i1" fill="#50C878"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

When I use *gthumb* or *GIMP* to display the svg, it prints the correct green square. However, when I include this block of code in *Chromium* or *Firefox*, the block appears in the html tree but nothing is display. This is the first time I use svg: after several researches on Google, I can't find anything....

Does someone know why it doesn't work ?

## Edit

Solve with the answer:

```html
<use xlink:href="#i1">
```

Comment: `<use xlink:href="#i1"` Also: I would put the `<defs>` outside the transformed group

Comment: Thanks! It works. I guess there is a difference between svg in html and in a document but why ?

Comment: In your code you are using an inexistent attribute, probably a typo. This can't work anywhere